# How to increase the number of MapReduce jobs on WSO2 BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am using WSO2 BAM 2.4.1 to run Hive Analytic scripts and by default, it only kicks off 1 MapReduce job as seen below. Need helps about how to configure WSO2 BAM to run multiple jobs instead.

Thanks!

> Total MapReduce jobs = 1
>
> Launching Job 1 out of 1

Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator

Answer (score 2):

Standalone WSO2BAM doesn't start hadoop server internally, rather it uses the hadoop as library, and do a direct JVM call to run the hadoop jobs. Hence you can't have actual parallel job execution with many jobs launched with standalone BAM. To achieve this you need to configure external hadoop cluster and submit the job remotely to the cluster. See [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Fully-Distributed%2C+High-Availability+BAM+Setup#Fully-Distributed,High-AvailabilityBAMSetup-Hadoopcluster) for the configuration of hadoop cluster.